# Can Crystal Reports Scale to Fit Page

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Can a crystal report be scaled to fit page?

I'm hoping to achieve something similar to Microsoft Excel's Scale To Fit feature wherein a large spreadsheet can be scaled to fit a 8.5"x 11" page.
(On MS Excel 2007 goto Page Layout > Scale To Fit).

Im searching of a way to make a large report fit into a smaller page during print.
for example a report designed in Legal(8.5"x 14") page must be able to shrink when print 
previewed for Letter(8.5"x 11") page.

In my crystal report, it should be scaled to fit the page by default.
I was thinking maybe theres a Crystal Report Setting or C# code technique that I missed out.

Any hint or link to the right direction is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. The report designer only gives you the amount of space on whatever page size you're designing for. So, it's already fit to the page.

Comment: @dotjoe,Thats right. But lets say we have around 500 crystal reports designed in a particular
page size, Then management suddenly requires that all those reports be printed in a different 
page size.Does that mean that the only way is to re-design all those reports for the new page 
size? I was hoping to simply add a page-scaling feature to the print preview part of the software
(if possible). 
Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Hmmm, the report probably wouldn't need to be changed too much if you're only changing the page height. Maybe you can programmatically hack into the ReportDocument object and change the page/print setting. I'm not sure if it is something that can be set on the fly, you might need to have a different file for each page size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the paper size programmatically, you will lose some of the canvas (hence fields).

Moreover, I'm not aware of any native API calls to scale the report as you request.

Workarounds:

- print the report to PDF.  In my experience, the Acrobat viewer will automatically scale the document to 8.5" x 11".  Take a look at the article I wrote about **correcting** the automatic scaling: [Adobe Acrobat – Printing Legal Landscape Documents](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2008/05/01/adobe-acrobat-printing-legal-landscape-documents/)
- export the report to Excel, then use its shrink-to-fit option.
- create a custom printer driver (akin to MS XPS image writer) to scale the image before printing--clearly not an easy task